# what is noir.server/start option :ns for?

Tags: clojure, noir

What is the `:ns` key for the option map supplied to `noir.server/start` used for? I see that if you leave out `:ns` a randomly generated symbol is used. From looking through the Noir source I could not find anywhere where this symbol is used. Does anyone know if this is currently being used for something / if there are plans for this key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [this file](https://github.com/ibdknox/noir/blob/master/src/noir/exception.clj) in Noir source code. This provides a middle ware to handle exceptions - `wrap-exceptions` and the code in this file uses `:ns` option to parse the exception and get stack trace data in a map object which has this `:ns` key.